# Transaction com Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, transações, lock

```
DB::connection('gtsql')->beginTransaction();
$seriefat = DB::connection('gtsql')->table('se_seriefat')
                                   ->where('c_codserie', 'FO')->first();

echo $seriefat->c_numultdoc;

sleep(15);

DB::connection('gtsql')->commit();
```

Se Executar neste tempo de 15 segundos um update neste registro da tabela se_seriefat... ele funciona normal nao deveria me retornar um erro de lock?

Estou utilizando SQLSRV

Comment: Nesse código não tem `update` !!!

Comment: Então, mas so funciona se eu der um $seriefat->save() ? Certo nao seria ele ficar em lock, travado o registro ate eu der commit() ?

Comment: ideia serai isso aqui nao funcionar..   $seriefat = SerieFat::where('c_codserie','FO')->first();


    $seriefat->c_numultdoc = $seriefat->c_numultdoc + 1;
    if ($seriefat->save()) {
      echo 'Atualizaou';
    } else {
      echo 'Não Atualizou';
    }